# Keep version number in one place in project

Tags: version-control, version

I have a project which when being set up for release, needs the version number in several places.

1. In the source code, so I can display the version number to the user when the software is running.
2. in the name of the executable, say, `myprogr2-1.exe`
3. in the folder name where it is to be installed, say, `c:\Program Files\MyProg-2.1\`
4. in the name of the installer, say, `MyProgr-2.1-Win32-Setup.exe`

And so forth...

The challange is to find a way to do this so I can keep the one version number in one place, rather than having to update it in in seveal files (cause I will allways forget one).

Are there anyone out there knowing about cunning ways to do this?

Comment: version.cfg ???.............

Answer (score 0):

You could put your version into a config file and write a batch / bash script to replace a string in all your files and filenames. For example you would put %version% everywhere where it shall be replaced. And before release you just run that batch / bash script.